# disable anonymous access to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB on Windows 2012 Server and running it on windows service.

In order to protect it from anonymous log-ins, I followed below steps to enable authenticate and disable anonymous access

[Create the Administrator Credentials and then Enable Authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

1. Start the `mongod` or `mongos` instance without the `auth` or `keyFile`setting.
2. Create the administrator user as described in `Create a User Administrator`.
3. Re-start the `mongod` or `mongos` instance with the `auth` or `keyFile` setting.

According to documentation, by running this shell command

> `db.auth(<username>,<password>)`

it should turn on authorization and restarting the instance it should disable anonymous  access.

I am not sure what 3rd step is meant, I stopped MongoDB service and restarted it.
**But I can still do a anonymous Log-in to the remote MongoDB**

How can I disable anonymous access to MongoDB?

**Update**

**Executing db.serverCmdLineOpts()**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "argv" : [ 
        "c:\\Program Files\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod.exe", 
        "--directoryperdb", 
        "--dbpath", 
        "c:\\mongodb\\data", 
        "--logpath", 
        "c:\\mongodb\\log\\mongodb_master.log", 
        "--logappend", 
        "--rest", 
        "--service"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "dbpath" : "c:\\mongodb\\data",
        "directoryperdb" : true,
        "logappend" : true,
        "logpath" : "c:\\mongodb\\log\\mongodb_master.log",
        "rest" : true,
        "service" : true
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This means I don't have auth key. How can i set auth key there?

Comment: To be clear on your "anonymous login" that still works; are you able to view/create data? You need to be able to connect anonymously to run the auth command, but you won't have any permissions to run any other commands if auth is enabled. For example, `show databases` will return an error like `listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To fully disable anonymous authentication you need to ensure that you:

#### 1) [Add an administrative user](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) to the `admin` database.

Until the first admin user is created, by default there is a [`localhost bypass`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#localhost-exception) that allows you to login anonymously and set up that first user.

To check you have at least one user in your admin database, run:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').system.users.find()
```

#### 2) Start your MongoDB server with `auth` enabled (standalone server) or `keyFile` enabled (replica set).

The `keyFile` option implies `auth`, and is used for internal authentication between replica set nodes.

To check the configuration settings for a running MongoDB instance, you can refer to the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` in a `mongo` shell.

If the options have been changed from the default they should show up in the `parsed`  section of the output. That is, one of these should return true:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.auth
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.keyFile
```

Comment: i noticed there is no auth key in parsed object. I have updated my question with db.serverCmdLineOpts() result. How can I add auth key there?

Comment: Thank you i was able to do a clean installation and set eh authorization working correctly. Will replicate the same steps on other server

Comment: @HaBo: since your `mongod` is running with the `--service` option, I'm guessing you followed the steps to [Run MongoDB as a Windows Service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-and-run-the-mongodb-service). That would have included setting up a configuration file (eg. `c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg`). You would add need to add `auth=true` to the config file and then restart the MongoDB service via `net stop MongoDB` and `net start MongoDB`.

Comment: i create admin user with superuser privileges ('root' role) :| that didn't work, yet it need admin user which is less privileged?

Comment: @deadManN As a starting point you should consult the [Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) documentation for the version of MongoDB you are using. If you are still having issues, please post a new question with details of what you've tried, any error message(s), and your specific environment: O/S, MongoDB server version, deployment type (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster). Questions on MongoDB administration are also more on-topic for [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: i checked there, not much i found, but searching through lot of question, i grant many thing, it give me not authorized error... i also joined DBA class of mongoDB, nothing much, then i asked the teacher, he asked more question, no answer yet...

Comment: @deadManN If there doesn't seem to be documentation or an existing question that addresses your situation, I'd ask a new question on DBA StackExchange. As mentioned, you need to include details of your environment (specific MongoDB server and O/S version, deployment type, error message, etc), what you've tried, and any error message(s).

Comment: @Stennie i just register MongoDb classes, and asked what happened from teacher, after some Q/A, he left the question unattended, i think it was unexpected even for him. maybe it's a bug or something.

Comment: @deadManN Please post a new question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) including all the details I've suggested earlier: what you've tried, any error message(s), and your environment details (O/S version, MongoDB server version, MongoDB deployment type). Without any information about your environment and what you've tried, the only suggestion I'd have is to read the documentation for your version of MongoDB.

Comment: @Stennie thank you dear stennie, since it's not like lot of people use mongo, and so there are little people with such issue, this time i'll get ban if i ask a question which no one attent much :D last time i got the 2 month ban and warning, since all my question target very specific subject. i think i pass. also i noticed once i create user which name was not admin, it started to work... maybe a bug, since also the security teacher said it should work even with admin as user name

Comment: @deadManN There are more than 84,000 `mongodb` questions on StackOverflow at the moment, another 1,200 on DBA StackExchange, and 100s of thousands of students who have taken courses at MongoDB University. There are many users willing to help if you'd like to post a new question on DBA with details of your situation. If your questions need improvement the community will provide feedback and you should try to follow those suggestions before posting more questions. I'd first suspect usage error rather than a bug since auth is widely used, but you haven't provided any real details yet ;-)

Comment: @Stennie My teacher at mongodb did not answer my question, in a way that i can solve it, and he said it should work, but here's the data: { "_id" : "admin.admin", "user" : "admin", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000,
 "salt" : "k96PCEflidMY5seVju+gAw==", "storedKey" : "CabQTnJtny7cv0wT5X8oX9QOn3A=", "serverKey" : "RJyCdnlIhyIfj2+d44L61
bYK+MU=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" },
 { "role" : "dbAdmin", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "userAdmin", "db" : "admin" }

Comment: , { "role" : "root", "db" : "admin" } ]
 }
{ "_id" : "admin.deadManN", "user" : "deadManN", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" :
10000, "salt" : "pZDQsQbQYYJhsa4XWMWhiw==", "storedKey" : "pMO0vrB1pXyKQ5nHuy8mZzrrSQM=", "serverKey" : "+zfKtTuM2TaeQU9
akQT/QyrRqBo=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" } ] }    ------- authentication for admin user failes, i even tried change password to make sure of this.

Comment: @Stennie as i mention i got hacked, so i though maybe something is missing, so i delete data folder and log , and relaunch the server, now the admin return 1, and also gives me permission to access data. BTW thanks

Answer (score 11):

Enabling authorization in version 2.6+ - it's in yml format:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

### Extra Information:

also note if you are using security config such as key file configuration, the

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

key is not required, that's why you may see config files without this flag...
another note:
in recent versions, 4.x you also need to configure access IP list:
    net:
        bindIp: ::,0.0.0.0 #to bind all v4 and v6 ip addresses, or use specific address which your specific host access, *recommended for production*

or

```
net:
    net.bindIpAll: true #to bind all ip addresses
```

Comment: You have to do it in the mongodb config file: ```sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf``` and don't forget to restart mongodb after that: ```sudo service mongod restart```

Comment: @tsveti_iko Thanks for the info, BTW, i'm a windows user and i didn't got involved with that path, i launch it where ever i launch my mongo from, or it was from where ever i have my data directory on, i don't remember at this time

Answer (score 2):

You have to restart the mongod instance with the --auth command line option (run it in the shell):

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Keep in mind that the path to mongodb can be different, so you can check the `dbPath` value in the mongodb config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what 3rd step is meant

Following the documentation to [Install MongoDB On Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)...

> You should specify two options when running MongoDB as a Windows
>   Service: a path for the log output (i.e. logpath) and a configuration
>   file.

This means that your `mongod` command (as defined in your Windows service) should look something like this:

```
c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg
```

In your configuration file (whatever it is called, mongod.cfg in my above example) you will want to have a line like this:

```
auth = true
```

Try that, and see if it works.  If your service definition does not contain the "--config" option, then re-install your service (following the doc I referenced) to add it.

Comment: I have my mongodb run as service. I guess we can do it either from service or from config file. Now If i try to run this command c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg I get "ERROR: could not read from config file"

Comment: From a command or Powershell window, what output do you get when you do a `type c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg`?  If it is not found, then you need to create it.  Your config file doesn't have to be named mongod.cfg.  It just has to be readable in a location that your user has access to.

Comment: it is using command prompt. So I created mongod.cfg under "C:\Program Files\mongodb" and ran this command on cmd .... mongod.exe --config ....mongod.cfg and i get the error"Could not read from config file" and gives me other allows options --help --h

Comment: I see the problem I had Mongodb in C:\\Program Files\mongodb and command was not running form that path, so I changed the path to c:\\mongodb. But adding config file with auth = true did not restrict to remote anonymous access while I run the MongoDB to as service. But it is checking for credentials when I run MONGODB manually